# Access View generated with union using JPA

Tags: hibernate, jpa, union

From what I've read online, JPA 2.0 does not support UNION in SQL queries.  That's annoying but nothing that can't be resolved.  So, I decided to create a view in the database which aggregates the desired data from the necessary tables.  Therefore JPA is dealing with just a simple select statement instead of UNIONS.  However, the view query is generated with UNION operators.  I have validated the data and it is valid.

**Example of Table:**

```
Country      Flow        Year 1       Year 2
--------------------------------------------    
France        A            25            78  
France        B            11            16  
France        C            18            88  
Russia        A            04            12  
Russia        B            86            99  
Russia        C            43            25
```

My thought was that I would then perform a simple "SELECT * FROM schema.view_name".  It retrieves some of the data in the view and then duplicates it.  There are 3 tables which are union-ed together.

**Data returned from view:**

```
Country      Flow        Year 1       Year 2
----------------------------------------------
France        A            25            78
France        A            25            78
France        A            25            78
Russia        A            04            12
Russia        A            04            12
Russia        A            04            12
```

Will the approach of using a view instead of passing a native SQL with the UNION operator not work?  If so, why not?  What would be some other approaches that I could take to work around this limitation?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can of course do that or also use a native query and map that to an entity, but it's a pain and isn't very dynamic.

You will love to hear that I created a library called [Blaze-Persistence](https://github.com/Blazebit/blaze-persistence#core-quick-start) that works on top of JPA and supports set operations as well as many other advanced DBMS features on top of the JPA model. Here is a simple example from the [documentation](https://persistence.blazebit.com/documentation/1.5/core/manual/en_US/#normal-set-operations) that showcases how a union query can be done:

```
FinalSetOperationCriteriaBuilder<Cat> cb = 
    cbf.create(em, Cat.class)
        .from(Cat.class, "cat")
        .where("name").eq("Billy")
    .unionAll() 
        .from(Cat.class, "cat")
        .where("name").eq("Johnny")
    .endSet();
```